# Mongoose fineOne does not work but find does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

findOne gets undefined in the result:

```
Upload.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (err, upload) {
  if (err || !upload) return;
  console.log(upload.name); /* Empty string */
});
```

However using find instead does get the result:

```
Upload.find({_id: req.params.id}, function (err, upload) {
  upload = upload[0];
  if (err || !upload) return;
  console.log(upload.name); /* it prints out what is expected */
});
```

I confirmed in both cases that the mongo query is run successfully and through the mongoDB shell both returned the expected result:

```
Mongoose: uploads.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("57196fced4595c2a09146891") }) { fields: undefined }
Mongoose: uploads.find({ _id: ObjectId("57196f0a8d2055520894d5a4") }) { fields: undefined }
```

Mongoose model:

```
const UploadSchema = new Schema ({
  name: {type: String, default: '', trim: true},
  mimetype: {type: String, default: '', trim: true}
});

UploadSchema.path('name').required(true, 'Name cannot be blank.');
UploadSchema.path('mimetype').required(true, 'Mimetype cannot be blank.');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Upload', UploadSchema);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Node version: 5.10. 1, Mongoose version: 4.4.10

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using Express, `req.params.id` will be a string; have you tried `Upload.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) })`?

Comment: As you can see in the debug console output, mongoose converts the string `req.params.id` to ObjectId automatically. I've also tried to convert it manually `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` but it didn't help...

Comment: Did the ObjectId is really exists 57196fced4595c2a09146891, 57196f0a8d2055520894d5a4 ?

Comment: Yeah, they both did exist in the collection.